# Line integrals with triangle vertices

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

> Evaluate the work integral where $F(x,y)=\langle-y,x\rangle$ over a triangle with vertices $A(-2,-2)$, $B(2,-2)$, $C(0,1)$.

I am not sure how to approach this problem. 
I tried setting $AB(4,0)$, $BC(-2,3)$ and $CA(-2,-3)$ but I am not sure how to proceed.

Without using Green's theorem

Comment: To parametrize the triangular path, remember that the line segment starting at point $P(x_0,y_0)$ and ending at $Q(x_1,y_1)$ is $$\big(x(t),y(t)\big) = P(x_0,y_0) +t\big[Q(x_1,y_1)-P(x_0,y_0)\big]$$ for $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: If it is a loop integration you can apply Green's theorem and convert the integration into an area integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to split this line integral into three. The first being the line integral from A to B, second from B to C, and third from C to A. The first line integral is along the line $y=-2$ and it is from $ x =-2$ to $x=2$. Thus, it can be parametrized as $x=t$ and $y=-2$ where $-2 \le t \le 2$. From this, we get the integral: $$\int_{-2 }^2 <2,t> . <1,0> dt$$ (The dot means dot product)
Using this, I think you can do the rest! Comment if you need more information/help :)

Comment: are the segments the one that I wrote above or are they different. Alsom for the first integral the answer would be 0 right?

Comment: I dont think so. For the segments, I usually first find the line that they are on (y=mx+b), and then I parametrize it by setting x to t and thus having an expression for y in terms of t. Then I find the bounds of t by solving for the value of t that gives each point. 

Also, yes the integral above is 0.

Comment: Im sorry. Could you give a more detailed explanation or procedure on doing the firs integral and from there I'll try the other two and come out with an answer

Comment: So the equation of the line containing point A and point B is y = -2. So I set x = t. t must be between -2 and 2 in order to give the points observed. The work integral is integral of F.dr where r is the position vector, in this case <t,-2>. Does this help?

Comment: For the second integral, both points lie on the line  $y= \frac{-3}{2} x + 1$. Next, I set $x=t$ and so we have $y= \frac{-3}{2} t + 1$. Also, t must be between 0 and 2 in order to give the end points of the segment we are given

Comment: Does that help at all?

Comment: so I got y=-3/2x +1 for BC and y=3/2x+1 for CA

Comment: ohh I did not see your comment

Comment: nice now parametrize them by setting x =  t, obtain and expression for y in terms of t, and then ur start value of x is ur start value of t (lower bound in the integral) and the end value is the upper bound!

Comment: however I got positive for CA

Comment: I dont get how you get your bounds

Comment: your lower bound is 0 and upper is -2 right? if so, then even if you got a positive value then you are fine

Comment: imagine im walking along the line segment. Where I start is my starting value of t and where I end is my end value. Im starting at C, and then going down to A for CA.

Comment: ok so now all three integrals are AB from -2 to 2 <0,t>.<1,0>

Comment: BC from 0 to 2 and CA from 0 to 2

Comment: BC starts at B then goes to C so it should be 2 to 0. CA starts at C and then goes to A so 0 to -2

Comment: John's method of doing the parameterization might make more sense to you. I edited some silly errors in my answer by the way

Answer (score 3):

The three segments $AB,BC,CA$ can each be parameterized on the interval $[0,1]$ as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
(1-t)A+tB=(1-t)\langle-2,-2\rangle+t\langle2,-2\rangle&=&\langle-2+4t,-2\rangle\\
(1-t)B+tC=(1-t)\langle2,-2\rangle+t\langle0,1\rangle&=&\langle2-2t,-2+3t\rangle\\
(1-t)C+tA=(1-t)\langle0,1\rangle+t\langle-2,-2\rangle&=&\langle-2t,1-3t\rangle
\end{eqnarray}

The differential vectors $\langle dx,dy\rangle$ for the three respective segments are $\langle4,0\rangle dt,\langle-2,3\rangle dt,\langle-2,-3\rangle dt$

Thus

\begin{equation}
\int_{AB}-y\,dx+x\,dy=\int_0^1(2)(4)+(2-4t)(0)dt=\int_0^18\,dt=8
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int_{BC}-y\,dx+x\,dy=\int_0^1(2-3t)(-2)+(2-2t)(3)dt=\int_0^12\,dt=2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int_{CA}-y\,dx+x\,dy=\int_0^1(-1+3t)(-2)+(-2t)(-3)dt=\int_0^12\,dt=2
\end{equation}

Therefore,

\begin{equation}
\int_{ABC}-y\,dx+x\,dy=8+2+2=12
\end{equation}

Comment: Green's theorem also gives a result of $12$.